# How can I get my animation to reset each time the state of my component is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-redux

I have a fade-in animation I want to use for a particular parent component. The problem is, the animation only occurs the first time the component is rendered. When I change the state by clicking a button, the animation does not reset and get triggered again.

This is in a react-redux application. I haven't tried adding an action and reducer and then utilizing componentDidMount(). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the component that renders the data:

```
export class Doctors extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchProfileInfo(this.props.user.id));
    }

render() {
    if (this.props.profile.doctors) {
        const cards = this.props.profile.doctors.map((d, i) => {
            return {
                previous: i === 0 ? null : i - 1,
                next: i === this.props.profile.doctors.length - 1 ? null : i + 1,
                doctor: d
            };
        });
    const d = cards[this.props.currentDoctor].doctor;
    console.log('this.props.profile.doctors', this.props.profile.doctors);
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <NavigationBar />
                <main role="main">
                    <h1 className="doctors-h1">Doctors</h1>
                    <div className="doctor-display-section">
                        <Doctor doctor={d} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="doctor-button-holder">
                        <button
                            className={this.props.currentDoctor !== 0 ? 'display-doctor-button-1' : 'hidden-1'}
                            onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(updateCurrentDoctor(cards[this.props.currentDoctor].previous))}
                        >
                            <p className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></p>
                            <p className="display-profile-section-button-p">
                                {cards[this.props.currentDoctor].previous === null ? '' : cards[this.props.currentDoctor - 1].doctor.name.firstName +
                                ' ' + cards[this.props.currentDoctor - 1].doctor.name.lastName}
                            </p>
                        </button>
                        <button
                            className={this.props.currentDoctor !== cards.length - 1 ? 'display-doctor-button-2' : 'hidden-1'}
                            onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(updateCurrentDoctor(cards[this.props.currentDoctor].next))}
                        >
                            <p className="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></p>
                            <p className="display-profile-section-button-p">
                                {cards[this.props.currentDoctor].next === null ? '' : cards[this.props.currentDoctor + 1].doctor.name.firstName +
                                ' ' + cards[this.props.currentDoctor + 1].doctor.name.lastName}
                            </p>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </main>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
            loading...
        </div>
    );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.auth.currentUser,
    profile: state.app.profile,
    currentDoctor: state.app.currentDoctor
});

export default requiresLogin()(connect(mapStateToProps)(Doctors));
```